# Find out what is playing audio

Tags: macos, safari, catalina

Lately I've been getting lots of bugs: songs from Safari playing without me starting them, or pausing youtube but it doesn't support but Safari says there is no sound from the tab, closing the tab doesn't stop it, or accidentally pasting a URL into Spotlight then being unable to stop the audio that starts playing.

I would like to know how to

1. Find out what is playing audio
2. Stop it

Or, just 2 actually.

I want to stop unwanted audio from playing.

This happens on brand new Catalina 10.15.2

Comment: Have you paired any Bluetooth devices recently with the Mac in question? Also, if closing a tab doesn't stop the audio, then the audio wasn't coming from that tab, so you may want to consider other possibilities. Seems to me that an embedded video on a page you've loaded somewhere is being triggered to play by something, such as bluetooth headphones, a keypress, etc.

Comment: @Monomeeth never paired bluetooth since reinstalling Catalina. There is no speaker symbol on any Safari tab, the audio was identical to the youtube video that was playing. I was playing a youtube video, paused it.... it kept playing. Then I tried to stop it in all the ways I described. It even started playing the next video in the playlist but stopped for some reason halfway through.

Answer (score 1):

If this happens in Safari, the tab for a site that is playing audio
will have a small speaker icon on it. See the image below which shows 3 tabs in the top of my Safari window. Clicking on the
speaker icon stops it from playing. See the middle tab in the image.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't, and that's why I am confused.

Comment: oh, I don't know why it isn't showing. I checked Safari preferences but couldn't find anything. No wonder you are confused..

Answer (score 0):

Bring out notification Centre by clicking the 3 bar icon in the menubar or swiping from the right side of the trackpad. It has a section "Now Playing".

Unless there are multiple sources of audio, it shows which app is playing the sound. And this controls which app gets the inputs of media  control keys.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything in the Notification Center (as another answer suggested), but I did find it in the options menu thingee—I don't recall the official name, but you can see it in the photo.  (If you're using a screen reader I apologize.  I'll try to find the correct name and update this when I can.)  I'm still using Monterrey—12.6.6 (21G646)—so your mileage may vary.

[image: The options menu dropdown whose name I don't recall]

This lets you turn it off quite easily, without knowing which app it is coming from.

Once I had neutralized the irritant, I checked different apps.  I didn't find anything in Safari (looking for audio icons on the tabs) but turned to Brave (Chrome, basically, but better) and found the culprit there thanks to  an icon in the toolbar next to the extensions:
[image: the drop down from Brave's audio menu]

I verified that that is not an extension, but it built into Brave (and possibly to Chrome therefore).

If you want to find the actual tab, rather than just stop it from playing, Brave has (and Chrome has) a Task Manager in the Window menu that will list every single tab separately.  Open that and you can find the tab and close it or do whatever else you want to it.